# hashmap custom override value when duplicate key occurred

Tags: java, hashmap

I am new to java, I have a hashmap , i have to insert key as age and value as count, ie

```
         HashMap<Integer,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
         hashMap.put(1,1);
         hashMap.put(2,1);
         hashMap.put(3,1);
         hashMap.put(1,1);  // whenever i insert this ,according to hashmap, it will override, but i want to customise like  the value should be incremented , ie the value of key 1 should be 2, again if i insert with  
         hashMap.put(1,1); // the value of key 1 should be 3.
```

i want to customize overriding value , while adding duplicate key.

i have done in the following way

```
         if(hashMap.containsValue(1)){
             Integer i = hashMap.get(1);
             i++;
             hashMap.put(1, i);
         }else{
             hashMap.put(1, 1);
         }
```

is there any best way than this ?
please suggest

Comment: The "best" way is related to your project, so it not easy to suggest a "best" way. But you could create a class which holds your `HashMap` and this class could provide methods like `get` and `put`. Then in the `put` method you can increment the value if the key is already in the map.

Comment: You can also use Guava's [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), quick and easy, and you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve this issue and yours will likely be fine.

If eg. you want to minimize the number of put-operations you could create a mutable Counter class, which wraps an integer (int primitive) and provides an increment method (counter++). Then you could use it like this:

```
     Map<Integer, Counter> ageMap;
     Integer age = ....;
     if(ageMap.containsValue(age)){
         ageMap.get(age).increment();
     }else{
         ageMap.put(age, new Counter(1));
     }
```

Comment: @SilentKnight a custom class you would have to write wrapping an integer and providing an increment method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can take a look at **Map.computeIfPresent()** method:

```
hashMap.computeIfPresent(aKey, (k, v) -> v + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `MyHashMap` class which extends `HashMap` and overrides `put`. Alternatively, you have a hashmap as a private field in `MyHashMap`, applying your already-written-code to a `put` method of `MyHashMap`.

Comment: I would advise against extending `HashMap`, as the semantics are vastly different and most operations won't make sense. It's better to create a custom class that wraps a hash map instead.

Comment: I would certainly not recommend doing it either, but it's a possibility. Updated answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Fair enough. I just want OP to realise that what he or she has is not a map, but a set.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, but in the name of nitpicking: It being a set isn't strictly true though, is it? Seeing as he needs to associate the count with an age.

Comment: It's a set with a multiplicity greater than 1. But you're right, they aren't strictly sets, they're bags.

Answer (score 0):

Tricks:

```
int[] ages=...;
HashMap<Integer,Integer> ageMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for(int i = 0;i < ages.length; i++){
    if(ageMap.contains(ages[i])){
        ageMap.put(ages[i], ageMap.get(ages[i])+1);
    } else {
        ageMap.put(ages[i], 1);
    }
}
```

And then, `ageMap` is the `Map` from `age` to `age count`;

Comment: @Tom Yes, you are right. I have re-edited my answer.